# Cannot mount guest additions with virtualbox

Tags: mount, virtualbox, shared-folders, eject

I am having the same problem as this: [Unable to mount VirtualBox Guest Additions as a guest (Win7 host)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80341/unable-to-mount-virtualbox-guest-additions-as-a-guest-win7-host) Choosing `Insert guest additions CD image...` from the `devices` tab on my virtual machine window gives me the same error prompt. The answer provided there says to use disk utility, but I am running this vm as a server and there is only the command line. How can I achieve what was provided here with just a CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can necessarily do this as easily as you would a GUI. I recommend adding Ubuntu Desktop (or some GUI) first, and then trying to insert the Guest Additions ISO. If that still doesn't work, try navigating to the ISO file and burning it on to an actual medium. From there, you should mount your host CD/DVD drive and install additions that way. It's possible to install Additions from CLI, but it will depend on what the CD name is in order to navigate to it. If it's more than one word, you need to put it in quotes. [Click this link to see how to do so](http://en.ig.ma/notebook/2012/virtualbox-guest-additions-on-ubuntu-server). Also make sure you have the necessary tools and dependencies installed! (I still recommend doing this with a GUI, though. [Here's how to install some GUIs onto Ubuntu Server.](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-gui-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-gnome/))