# Full screen mode in virtual box. Nothing helps

Tags: virtualbox

In previous versions of `Ubuntu` I followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80341/unable-to-mount-virtualbox-guest-additions-as-a-guest-win7-host) and manually did the trick. In fact, I did this:

```
cd /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.2.4_81684/
sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

But in a newer version of `Ubuntu`, I see that `/media` folder is empty. I next followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) and installed guest additions, but still I can't locate them and `/media` folder remains empty. Simply doing `Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image...` does not work, but results in a warning, saying that something `is inaccessible`. So, something wich should be just the most trivial thing in the world turns out to be a kind of sacred knowledge that only chosen ones know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue and found using this command worked. This was run on the VM not the host.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

After that just restart the the virtual machine.

Comment: Please make sure to keep important details concerning executing commands before the command itself. Some people may be anxious to have their issue solved and may by accident execute commands when they shouldn't.

Comment: Nice "solution", if only it worked.  But it didn't work.  I ran "sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms", and then restarted my virtual machine, and lo and behold - the same tiny screen.